# Where to find SDK 10.7 for Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, sdk

I am using Xcode 5.1 and want to compile my app against Base SDK 10.7. However I just see SDK 10.8 and 10.9.

Where can I find the 10.7 base SDK ? I use

```
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 1080
```

command to check sdk version at compilation time.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You usually want to compile with the latest available SDK and set the **deployment target** to the oldest version you want to support. In your case the SDK would be 10.9 and deployment target would be 10.7

Comment: I use the NSUserNotification class which is not supported under 10.7. If I set the deployment target to 10.7 but base SDB to 10.9, starting the application under 10.7 crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the "Compatibility" section in the following link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/00-Introduction/Introduction.html

> Xcode 5.1.1 requires a Mac running OS X v10.8.4 (or later), or OS X
>   v10.9. It includes SDKs for OS X v10.8, OS X v10.9, and iOS v7.1. To
>   develop apps targeting prior versions of OS X or iOS, see “About SDKs
>   and the iOS Simulator.”

Also with release of new OS's and SDK's, Apple deprecate the old deployment targets, and restrict us to submit using new Xcode version only. In such a case you cannot go back to 10.7.

Comment: I mark this one as solution because it helped me to find the answer. I had to use MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED instead of __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED to get the target deployment version.

Comment: However helpful it might have been, it is wrong (no offense). You can still get the old SDKs by downloading the old XCode from the developer portal, extracting the SDK installer from the package, installing it and copying it into the current XCode version you are using. You have to do this when you want to support older MacOS versions.

Answer (score 1):

https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.3.3_for_lion/xcode_4.3.3_for_lion.dmg

You'll need an Apple login to download the file, but you don't need a paid App Store developer account.

Mount the image, right-click Xcode.app, then Show Package Contents.  You will find MacOSX10.7.sdk in Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs.